# CDC log retention for Informix

Tags: informix, ibm-data-replication

Actual Situation:
We use IBM Data Replication (11.4)  to replicate Data from an Informix Database to an SQL Server Database.
Now we have an instance with 45 different subscriptions. On the informix side, we have 30 different log files.

The Problem:
When we want to “refresh” all subscriptions at once, we get in trouble that some logs aren’t available anymore, because they were overwritten. 
The problem is that these logs were not full to 100 percent, but instead only to approximately 0,5%.

I don’t know when exactly a new log will be created.

Is there any possibility to change the settings, at which time a new logfile will be created? or that a new logfile only will be created when it is full to 100% or something else? Or do you have another solution to that problem at all?

Answer (score 1):

We have found the problem:
The parameter “log_api_switch_log_num_pages” has to be defined. It describes log switching after a refresh.

See details here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21997830